# Check availability for multiple class elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Logic needed for the application**

If `Item1` & `Item2` & `Item3` Exists - Add `class 1`

If `Item1` & `Item2` Exists - Add `class 2`

If `Item1` & `Item3` Exists - Add `class 3`

If `Item1` Exists or `Item2` & `Item3` Not Exists - Add `class 4`

`Else` `Remove` all class items

Not sure how to code this logic in jquery. When i code, either one not working correctly. Please help to solve this issue.

```js
if ($(("li.item1") && ("li.item2") && ("li.item3")).length) {
  $(".content").addClass("1");
  $(".content").removeClass("2");
  $(".content").removeClass("3");
  $(".content").removeClass("4");
} else if ($(("li.item1") && ("li.item2")).length) {
  $(".content").addClass("2");
  $(".content").removeClass("1");
  $(".content").removeClass("3");
  $(".content").removeClass("4");
} else if ($(("li.item1") && ("li.item3")).length) {
  $(".content").addClass("3");
  $(".content").removeClass("1");
  $(".content").removeClass("2");
  $(".content").removeClass("4");
} else if (!$(("li.item2") && ("li.item3")).length) {
  $(".content").addClass("4");
  $(".content").removeClass("1");
  $(".content").removeClass("2");
  $(".content").removeClass("3");
} else {
  $(".content").removeClass("1");
  $(".content").removeClass("2");
  $(".content").removeClass("3");
  $(".content").removeClass("4");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item item3">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="selector">Test1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item item2">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="selector">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item item1">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="selector">Test2</a>
    <div class="content">
      <input id="search" name="search" class="search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS (classes) code for debugging.

Comment: HTML structure added.. Based on the class name. we are assigning width of the textbox in css

Comment: When removing classes, you can remove multiple classes by separating with a space. i.e. $('.content').removeClass('1 2 3'). To remove all classes you can use $('.content').attr('class',''). Also, you can do a lot in a single line. i.e. ('.content').removeClass('1 2 3').addClass('4')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/ec1gohtf/)

***JQuery***:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").each(function() {
    if ($("li").hasClass("item1") && $("li").hasClass("item2") &&
      $("li").hasClass("item3")) {
      $(".content").removeClass("2 3 4").addClass("1");
    } else if ($("li").hasClass("item1") && $("li").hasClass("item2")) {
      $(".content").removeClass("1 3 4").addClass("2");
    } else if ($("li").hasClass("item1") && $("li").hasClass("item3")) {
      $(".content").removeClass("1 2 4").addClass("3");
    } else if (!$("li").hasClass("item2") && !$("li").hasClass("item3")) {
      $(".content").removeClass("1 2 3").addClass("4");
    } else {
      $(".content").removeClass("1 2 3 4");
    }
  });
});

HTML:
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item1 item3">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="selector">Test1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item item2">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="selector">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="item item1">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="selector">Test2</a>
    <div class="content">
      <input id="search" name="search" class="search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(("li").hasClass("item1") && ("li").hasClass("item2") && ("li")).hasClass("item3")){
     // then it will work
}
```

Add this for all conditions..

and there is clean solution too for this..

```
if($(li.item1.item2.item3).length > 0){
   // add your class..
}
```